# Getting touch coordinates not accurate in ImageView FloodFill Algorithm

Tags: java, android, algorithm, coordinates, flood-fill

I'm trying to use a Fill Flood algorithm for make a Cube Painting tool for an app.

This is the code of the algorithm:

```
public class QueueLinearFloodFiller {

protected Bitmap image = null;
protected int[] tolerance = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };
protected int width = 0;
protected int height = 0;
protected int[] pixels = null;
protected int fillColor = 0;
protected int[] startColor = new int[] { 0, 0, 0 };
protected boolean[] pixelsChecked;
protected Queue<FloodFillRange> ranges;

// Construct using an image and a copy will be made to fill into,
// Construct with BufferedImage and flood fill will write directly to
// provided BufferedImage
public QueueLinearFloodFiller(Bitmap img) {
    copyImage(img);
}

public QueueLinearFloodFiller(Bitmap img, int targetColor, int newColor) {
    useImage(img);

    setFillColor(newColor);
    setTargetColor(targetColor);
}

public void setTargetColor(int targetColor) {
    startColor[0] = Color.red(targetColor);
    startColor[1] = Color.green(targetColor);
    startColor[2] = Color.blue(targetColor);
}

public int getFillColor() {
    return fillColor;
}

public void setFillColor(int value) {
    fillColor = value;
}

public int[] getTolerance() {
    return tolerance;
}

public void setTolerance(int[] value) {
    tolerance = value;
}

public void setTolerance(int value) {
    tolerance = new int[] { value, value, value };
}

public Bitmap getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void copyImage(Bitmap img) {
    // Copy data from provided Image to a BufferedImage to write flood fill
    // to, use getImage to retrieve
    // cache data in member variables to decrease overhead of property calls
    width = img.getWidth();
    height = img.getHeight();

    image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawBitmap(img, 0, 0, null);

    pixels = new int[width * height];

    image.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 1, 1, width - 1, height - 1);
}

public void useImage(Bitmap img) {
    // Use a pre-existing provided BufferedImage and write directly to it
    // cache data in member variables to decrease overhead of property calls
    width = img.getWidth();
    height = img.getHeight();
    image = img;

    pixels = new int[width * height];

    image.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 1, 1, width - 1, height - 1);
}

protected void prepare() {
    // Called before starting flood-fill
    pixelsChecked = new boolean[pixels.length];
    ranges = new LinkedList<>();
}

// Fills the specified point on the bitmap with the currently selected fill
// color.
// int x, int y: The starting coords for the fill
public void floodFill(int x, int y) {
    // Setup
    prepare();

    if (startColor[0] == 0) {
        // ***Get starting color.
        int startPixel = pixels[(width * y) + x];
        startColor[0] = (startPixel >> 16) & 0xff;
        startColor[1] = (startPixel >> 8) & 0xff;
        startColor[2] = startPixel & 0xff;
    }

    // ***Do first call to floodfill.
    LinearFill(x, y);

    // ***Call floodfill routine while floodfill ranges still exist on the
    // queue
    FloodFillRange range;

    while (ranges.size() > 0) {
        // **Get Next Range Off the Queue
        range = ranges.remove();

        // **Check Above and Below Each Pixel in the Floodfill Range
        int downPxIdx = (width * (range.Y + 1)) + range.startX;
        int upPxIdx = (width * (range.Y - 1)) + range.startX;
        int upY = range.Y - 1;// so we can pass the y coord by ref
        int downY = range.Y + 1;

        for (int i = range.startX; i <= range.endX; i++) {
            // *Start Fill Upwards
            // if we're not above the top of the bitmap and the pixel above
            // this one is within the color tolerance
            if (range.Y > 0 && (!pixelsChecked[upPxIdx])
                    && CheckPixel(upPxIdx))
                LinearFill(i, upY);

            // *Start Fill Downwards
            // if we're not below the bottom of the bitmap and the pixel
            // below this one is within the color tolerance
            if (range.Y < (height - 1) && (!pixelsChecked[downPxIdx])
                    && CheckPixel(downPxIdx))
                LinearFill(i, downY);

            downPxIdx++;
            upPxIdx++;
        }
    }

    image.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 1, 1, width - 1, height - 1);
}

// Finds the furthermost left and right boundaries of the fill area
// on a given y coordinate, starting from a given x coordinate, filling as
// it goes.
// Adds the resulting horizontal range to the queue of floodfill ranges,
// to be processed in the main loop.

// int x, int y: The starting coords
protected void LinearFill(int x, int y) {
    // ***Find Left Edge of Color Area
    int lFillLoc = x; // the location to check/fill on the left
    int pxIdx = (width * y) + x;

    while (true) {
        // **fill with the color
        pixels[pxIdx] = fillColor;

        // **indicate that this pixel has already been checked and filled
        pixelsChecked[pxIdx] = true;

        // **de-increment
        lFillLoc--; // de-increment counter
        pxIdx--; // de-increment pixel index

        // **exit loop if we're at edge of bitmap or color area
        if (lFillLoc < 0 || (pixelsChecked[pxIdx]) || !CheckPixel(pxIdx)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    lFillLoc++;

    // ***Find Right Edge of Color Area
    int rFillLoc = x; // the location to check/fill on the left

    pxIdx = (width * y) + x;

    while (true) {
        // **fill with the color
        pixels[pxIdx] = fillColor;

        // **indicate that this pixel has already been checked and filled
        pixelsChecked[pxIdx] = true;

        // **increment
        rFillLoc++; // increment counter
        pxIdx++; // increment pixel index

        // **exit loop if we're at edge of bitmap or color area
        if (rFillLoc >= width || pixelsChecked[pxIdx] || !CheckPixel(pxIdx)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    rFillLoc--;

    // add range to queue
    FloodFillRange r = new FloodFillRange(lFillLoc, rFillLoc, y);

    ranges.offer(r);
}

// Sees if a pixel is within the color tolerance range.
protected boolean CheckPixel(int px) {
    int red = (pixels[px] >>> 16) & 0xff;
    int green = (pixels[px] >>> 8) & 0xff;
    int blue = pixels[px] & 0xff;

    return (red >= (startColor[0] - tolerance[0])
            && red <= (startColor[0] + tolerance[0])
            && green >= (startColor[1] - tolerance[1])
            && green <= (startColor[1] + tolerance[1])
            && blue >= (startColor[2] - tolerance[2]) && blue <= (startColor[2] + tolerance[2]));
}

// Represents a linear range to be filled and branched from.
protected class FloodFillRange {
    public int startX;
    public int endX;
    public int Y;

    public FloodFillRange(int startX, int endX, int y) {
        this.startX = startX;
        this.endX = endX;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}
```

}

This is the part where I handle the touch event on my ImageView:

```
filler.setTolerance(150);

    imagen.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            int x = (int)motionEvent.getX();
            int y = (int)motionEvent.getY();
            filler.prepare();
            filler.floodFill(x, y);
            imagen.setImageBitmap(filler.getImage());
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The problem is that the coordinates are not accurate. I mean, wherever I touch the image it gets painted in other part in which I haven't.

Do I need to treat my event coordinates before sending them to the Filler algorithm? I have also tried a full-screen image and this keeps happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your situation reminded me [this blog post](https://pristalovpavel.wordpress.com/2015/05/16/drawing-on-image-in-android/) as it might be the same problem he fixed there. He had to take into account the transformation the bitmap went through before it was put into the ImageView.

Instead of using just `getX()` and `getY()` on the event in his `OnTouchListener` he used `getPointerCoords(event)[0]` and `getPointerCoords(event)[1]` respectively and created this method:

```
 final float[] getPointerCoords(MotionEvent e)
{
    final int index = e.getActionIndex();
    final float[] coords = new float[] { e.getX(index), e.getY(index) };
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    getImageMatrix().invert(matrix); //his drawable view extends ImageView 
                                  //so it has access to the getImageMatrix.
    matrix.postTranslate(getScrollX(), getScrollY());
    matrix.mapPoints(coords);
    return coords;
}
```

Note that if indeed that's a solution for you - you can use the `getImageMatrix()` method on your `imagen` variable inside the method, or save the matrix into a final variable and use it in the `OnTouchListener`.

Also note that if that was the problem - you should also take the transformation into account when setting up the `FillFlood` to construct the dimensions accordingly (it would mean your previous attempt resulted in a too big/small a matrix compared to the original bitmap).

And all in one for you (one way to use this solution):

```
final Matrix transformationMatrix = new Matrix();
imagen.getImageMatrix().invert(transformationMatrix);
transformationMatrix.postTranslate(imagen.getScrollX(), imagen.getScrollY());
imagen.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        float[] transformedCoords = getPointerCoords(event);
        int x = (int)transformedCoords[0];
        int y = (int)transformedCoords[1];
        filler.prepare();
        filler.floodFill(x, y);
        imagen.setImageBitmap(filler.getImage());
        return false;
    }

    final float[] getPointerCoords(MotionEvent e) {
        final int index = e.getActionIndex();
        final float[] coords = new float[] { e.getX(index), e.getY(index) };
        transformationMatrix.mapPoints(coords);
        return coords;
    }
});
```

Hope that solves it.

Comment: Please, save the array resulting of `getPointerCoords` instead of doing some Matrix works twice.

Comment: @AxelH you're absolutely right. Changed that in the code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately the issue keeps happening. The part I touch is not the part thats get painted. By the way, methods 'getScrollX()' and 'getScrollY()' cannot be resolved. I guess it's imagen.getScrollX()? It does not need a View to be called?

Comment: Update: Sorry, I was using matrix incorrecly, my bad. It just works fine but just with some determined images. I guess it has to be to the way that they are adjusted and displayed in the device screen. If the image is too small enough to be displayed with its real dimensions, it works well; but when the image is resized to fix the device screen is just dont work as intended.

Comment: Sorry - you're right about the `getScrollX()`, `getScrollY()`. I'm updating those in the code. I didn't quite understand when does it work and when doesn't it work for you though.

Comment: When the image is small enough for be displayed in screen without been stretched, it's working fine. If the image is too big and it's automatically stretched to fit the screen then the painting stop working. It is happening the same if you fit the image to the whole screen with 'match_parent' attribute.

Comment: It sounds like situations where the `getPointerCoordinates` method should actually work and solve, transforming the touch events into the original bitmap's coordinates.